# Transforming an image classification model into a hierarchical model

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, resnet

I am using ResNet50 for extracting features from images. How I can remove the classification head of the network and  also because I need to split the network to have intermediate features how I can transform the network into such a hierarchical form that I can access to the intermediate network architecture as follows:

```
import torch
from torchvision.models import resnet50, ResNet50_Weights
import torch.nn as nn

class model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, pretrained=True):
        super(model, self).__init__()

        self.featureExtractor = resnet50(weights=ResNet50_Weights.IMAGENET1K_V2)

def forward(self, x):   
        
      x1= self.featureExtractor_1(x)     #(number of feature maps:256)
      x2= self.featureExtractor_2(x1)    # (number of feature maps:512)
      x3= self.featureExtractor_3(x2)    # (number of feature maps:1024)
      x4= self.featureExtractor_4(x3)    # (number of feature maps:2048)

 return x1, x2, x3, x4
```

Although I know how to extract the intermediate features of the network by using `hook` method I do not know to to split the network into such a hierarchy?

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You can do as follows:

```
import torch
from torchvision.models import resnet50, ResNet50_Weights
import torch.nn as nn

class model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(model, self).__init__()

        self.model = resnet50(weights=ResNet50_Weights.IMAGENET1K_V2)
        self.block1 = nn.Sequential(*list(self.model.children())[:5])
        self.block2 = nn.Sequential(*list(self.model.children())[5:6])
        self.block3 = nn.Sequential(*list(self.model.children())[6:7])
        self.block4 = nn.Sequential(*list(self.model.children())[7:8])


    def forward(self, x):   
        
        x1 = self.block1(x)    
        x2 = self.block2(x1)
        x3 = self.block3(x2)
        x4 = self.block4(x3)

        return(x1, x2, x3, x4)

x = torch.randn(1, 3, 256, 256)
model = model()
x1, x2, x3, x4 = model(x)

print(x1.shape, x2.shape, x3.shape, x4.shape)
```

Which gives:

```
torch.Size([1, 256, 64, 64]) torch.Size([1, 512, 32, 32]) torch.Size([1, 1024, 16, 16]) torch.Size([1, 2048, 8, 8])
```